# Deceleration with known drag force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, electric-current, drag

so by no means am I a physicist, but I've been working on a problem where I find that I may be very close to the solution...

I'm working on a model roller coaster car that will be slown down by using an eddy current brake. Using the formulas provided here (https://www.kjmagnetics.com/blog.asp?p=eddy-currents-2) I have calculated that given an initial speed of 7m/s, the drag force on the car will be 120 N.

I would like to know deceleration values and stopping distance. For now I understand that F=ma; so a = F/m.

If I use that equation I have a deceleration of -0.82m/s2. That gives a stopping distance of 3m. I'm not sure my thinking is correct here, because I find some sources that say that deceleration is the difference in forces (because the car has kinetic energy, it moves at 7m/s when hitting the brakes).

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deceleration force is not constant; it decreases as the speed of the coaster decreases.

I shall assume that braking happens on level ground and the aluminium plate is at least as long as the stopping distance. I don't know how you got the value of $F=120N$ when $u=7m/s$ but I shall assume that is correct.

The formula for braking force is $F=-kv$ where $k$ is some constant. This causes deceleration according to Newton's 2nd Law :

$$F=Ma=M\frac{dv}{dt}=Mv\frac{dv}{dx}=-kv$$ $$\frac{M}{k}\int_u^0 dv= -\int_0^s dx$$ $$s=\frac{M}{k}u$$

Here $s$ is stopping distance, $u$ is the speed of the coaster when it reaches the braking pad, and $M$ is the mass of the coaster. You calculated $F=120N$ when $u=7m/s$ therefore $k=\frac{120}{7}Ns/m$.

Answer (score 0):

the Force an thereby the accellaration is as far as I know proportional to the velocity? Than  you can not calculate with the constant a for 7m/s
a=-k*v(t) if you know k then $v(t)=v(0)*e^{-k*t}$ and $s(t)=s(0)-1/k*v(0)*e^{-k*t}$
this never gets to s=0 but it is just theory, just calculate the time for very small v.